# Task deadlock doesn't occur

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I found this example in the book. And it's written that this code leads to deadlock. But I don't get it and don't understand why it should be?
I always get

> “Locked B and A”
>
> “Locked A and B”

```
static void Main()
{
    object lockA = new object();
    object lockB = new object();
    var up = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lock (lockA)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lock (lockB)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(“Locked A and B”);
            }
        }
    });

    lock (lockB)
    {
        lock (lockA)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(“Locked B and A”);
        }
    }

    up.Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Try adding a Sleep in the main thread as well after you've acquired `lockB`.

Comment: 10/10 results are deadlocks. Why is it so? I thougt it should be some diversity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code isn't guaranteed to deadlock.  There is a race condition as to whether or not it will deadlock.  If the newly started task manages to grab the first lock before the main thread goes on to grab that same lock, then the code deadlocks, if (as is no doubt happening for you) the first thread manages to get both locks before the worker thread does anything, then there is no deadlock.

Comment: Thank you for answer. And the order of output isn't guaranteed as well? I just get only B-A, A-B and never A-B, B-A. Maybe I need to try more to get other result...

Comment: @Stalli While it's *technically* possible for the created task to end up running to completion first, in any practical sense, that is impossible, so you are unlikely to ever see that ordering.

Comment: Does it mean that main thread is usually goes first from the moment of task running?

Comment: @Stalli Typically.  It's already running, while it's *possible* for the thread scheduler to stop it just after scheduling a new thread to run, it's not particularly *likely* that it ends up being stopped right at that exact moment.

Comment: Thank you very much, Servy.